# Using regex matched groups in pandas dataframe replace function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just learning python/pandas and like how powerful and concise it is.

During data cleaning I want to use replace on a column in a dataframe with regex but I want to reinsert parts of the match (groups).

Simple Example:
lastname, firstname -> firstname lastname

I tried something like the following (actual case is more complex so excuse the simple regex):

```
df['Col1'].replace({'([A-Za-z])+, ([A-Za-z]+)' : '\2 \1'}, inplace=True, regex=True)
```

However, this results in empty values. The match part works as expected, but the value part doesn't.
I guess this could be achieved by some splitting and merging, but I am looking for a general answer as to whether the regex group can be used in replace.

Comment: Please share some data for testing.

Comment: or `df['Col1'].replace({'([A-Za-z]+), ([A-Za-z]+)' : '\\2 \\1'}, inplace=True, regex=True)`.

Comment: Really great! Just learning python as well, so please excuse the newbie mistake.

Additional question: Do both ways broadcast, i.e. are the both fast, the one via .str and the one using replace() directly?

Comment: @PeterD, `df.column.str.replace()` - should be bit faster compared to `df.column.replace({})`, but the second one aloows you to make a few replacements in one go

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think you have a few issues with the RegEx's.

As [@Abdou just said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472951/using-regex-matched-groups-in-pandas-dataframe-replace-function/41473130#comment70152014_41472951) use either `'\\2 \\1'` or better `r'\2 \1'`, as `'\1'` is a symbol with ASCII code `1`

Your solution should work if you will use correct RegEx's:

```
In [193]: df
Out[193]:
              name
0        John, Doe
1  Max, Mustermann

In [194]: df.name.replace({r'(\w+),\s+(\w+)' : r'\2 \1'}, regex=True)
Out[194]:
0          Doe John
1    Mustermann Max
Name: name, dtype: object

In [195]: df.name.replace({r'(\w+),\s+(\w+)' : r'\2 \1', 'Max':'Fritz'}, regex=True)
Out[195]:
0            Doe John
1    Mustermann Fritz
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, especially for the nice explanation how python regex works, Most examples I have seen are so simple they can omit the r syntax without problems, it seems.

Answer (score 13):

***setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(name=['Smith, Sean']))
print(df)

          name
0  Smith, Sean
```

***using `replace`***

```
df.name.str.replace(r'(\w+),\s*(\w+)', r'\2 \1')

0    Sean Smith
Name: name, dtype: object
```

***using `extract`***
split to two columns

```
df.name.str.extract('(?P<Last>\w+),\s*(?P<First>\w+)', expand=True)

    Last First
0  Smith  Sean
```

Comment: the way to get the named groups is what I was looking for.