# How to drop and keep only certain non alphanumeric characters?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace, non-alphanumeric

I Have df that looks like this:

```
email                                    id
{'email': ['test@test.com']}           {'id': ['123abc_d456_789_fgh']}
```

when I drop non alphanumeric characters like so:

```
df.email = df.email.str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '')
df.email = df.email.str.replace('email', '')


df.id = df.id.str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '')
df.id = df.id.str.replace('id', '')
```

The columns look like this:

```
email                    id
testtestcom              123abcd456789fgh
```

How do I tell the code to not drop anything in the square brackets but drop all non alpha numeric characters outside the brackets?

New df should like this:

```
email                        id
test@test.com                123abc_d456_789_fgh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hardcoded, but works:

```
df.email = df.email.str.replace(".+\['|'].+", '')
df.id = df.id.str.replace(".+\['|'].+", '')

>>> 'test@test.com'
>>> '123abc_d456_789_fgh'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, what you might do is capture what is in between the square brackets in a capturing group.

In the replacement use the first capturing group.

```
\{'[^']+':\s*\['([^][]+)'\]}
```

That will match

- `\{` Match `{`
- `'[^']+'` Match `'`, then not `'` 1+ times
- `:` Match literally
- `\s*\['` Match 0+ times a whitespace character and then `[`
- `([^][]+)` Capture group, match not `[` or `]`
- `'\]` Match `]`
- `}` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cqkXwC/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XJSGkQ)

Comment: `df.email = df.email.str.replace('(\[[^][]+\])|[^a-zA-Z]','')` drops everything but the word `email`

Comment: Your question is `How do I tell the code to not drop anything in the square brackets but drop all non alpha numeric characters outside the brackets?` email is inside the square brackets.

Comment: email is definitely not in square brackets. Its inside the squiggly bracket no?

Comment: I thought you wanted to keep email and do that in a separate replace because you used [^a-zA-Z]` If you want to remove all, the you might try `(\[[^][]+\])|.` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/YEJcBP/1) In that case, why not just match the values? `\[[^][]+\]` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/YEJcBP/2)

Comment: the above line removes everything. I just want to keep the email address and ID as is in the column, thats it.

Comment: So you have all the data and you want to keep the values  between the square brackets only like https://regex101.com/r/cqkXwC/1

Comment: that is exactly correct, could you please show me how to use in a replace?

Comment: @RustyShackleford I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I am using it in the line like this is it correct? `df.email = df.email.str.replace(r"'\{'[^']+':\s*\['([^][]+)'\]}'",'',regex=True)` currently this is doing nothing to the column, how do I use it in replace properly?

Comment: I think that now you are replacing it with an empty string, try using the first capturing group instead `df.email = df.email.str.replace(r"'\{'[^']+':\s*\['([^][]+)'\]}'",'\\1',regex=True)`

Comment: that also did not work, replaced everything with NaN, see Gianmar response above

Comment: Yes that works but does not take the data structure into account. If will also remove just a single `']` and all that precedes and follows.  There are examples of the first capturing group in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472951/using-regex-matched-groups-in-pandas-dataframe-replace-function)