# Search keyword of single column between 2 different dataframes and merge matched rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I'm new to python and pandas dataframes, I've been stuck on the following for a while:

I have two different dataframes: df1 has ~130 rows, df2 has ~380 rows

- `df1['Symbol_1']` has values like 'DASHUSDT' (for example) containing the keyword 'DASH'
- `df2['Symbol_2']` has values like 'DASHBTC' (for example) from df2 containing the keyword 'DASH'

I would like to search df2 by keyword from df1, and create a new dataframe (df3 like below).

- Note that all rows from df1 will always have a keyword matched from df2 except 'BTC/USDT' pair.
- To make things more clear: Symbol_1 (for example: DASHUSDT) always ends with 'USDT', and 'DASH' is the keyword. Symbol_2 (for example: DASHBTC) always ends with 'BTC', and 'DASH' is the keyword.
- I am creating a watchlist for USDT pairs, and I would like to check the BTC pairs from the same watchlist easily. BTC is the king, and all altcoins have a BTC pair, DASH/BTC, ETH/BTC, LTC/BTC etc. But BTC will not have a BTC pair like this BTC/BTC, so for the 'BTC/USDT' row, there will not have any matched rows from 2nd dataframe, so we can keep it empty or replace the 'Symbol_2' column with '0' and '24H_Change_2' column with '0'

**[df1]**

```
Symbol_1       Price    24H_Change_1  Volume

BTCUSDT        42135.15   -1.565      200.125
DASHUSDT       139.87     10.0390     1.7400
ADAUSDT        1.23060    1.0700      1.1800
C98USDT        2.5328     0.4520      1.1900
1000SHIBUSDT   0.029233   6.589       2.4564
```

**[df2]**

```
Symbol_2        24H_Change_2  

1000SHIBBTC     4.412
SNMBTC          5.1235    
ADABTC          1.0700     
XVGBTC          15.1240
C98BTC          0.4520
SALTBTC         7.149
EOSBTC          5.551
DASHBTC         11.258
```

**Output dataframe I want:** (1st option)

```
Symbol_1        Price      24H_Change_1   Volume    Symbol_2      24H_Change_2

BTCUSDT         42135.15   -1.565         200.125   
DASHUSDT        139.87     10.0390        1.7400    DASHBTC       11.258
ADAUSDT         1.23060    1.0700         1.1800    ADABTC        1.0700
C98USDT         2.5328     0.4520         1.1900    C98BTC        0.4520
1000SHIBUSDT    0.029233   6.589          2.4564    1000SHIBBTC   4.412
```

**Output dataframe I want:** (2nd option)

If 1st option is not possible or too much of a trouble or two complicated to accomplish, I am fine with 2nd option, I can separate 'BTC/USDT' pair from 1st dataframe out as a single dataframe for reference and then add a new dataframe (3rd dataframe like below) for altcoins.

```
Symbol        Price      24H_Change   Volume 

BTCUSDT       42135.15   -1.565       200.125
```

---

```
Symbol_1        Price      24H_Change_1   Volume    Symbol_2      24H_Change_2
  
DASHUSDT        139.87     10.0390        1.7400    DASHBTC       11.258
ADAUSDT         1.23060    1.0700         1.1800    ADABTC        1.0700
C98USDT         2.5328     0.4520         1.1900    C98BTC        0.4520
1000SHIBUSDT    0.029233   6.589          2.4564    1000SHIBBTC   4.412
```

Comment: Have a quick skim of the [pandas quickstart](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html) and also [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101). Then you will recognize this is a merge/join in disguise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. first **use string-replace operations to get your 'From' currency/token column**
2. then **merge df1, df2 with a [pandas merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)**.

You're making this too hard, you don't need to keep a watchlist, just index both dataframes. (There will be some index labels in df2 missing in df1, merge handles that automatically, see below.)

Given you know `df1['Symbol_1']` always ends in '...USDT' and `df2['Symbol_2']` always ends in '...BTC', just create a new index or 'From' column with a simple string-replacement to eliminate the destination currency/token, hence: 'BTC', 'DASH', 'ADA'.

```
df1 = df1.set_index(df1['Symbol_1'].str.replace('(.*)USDT', r'\1', regex=True))
```

Note we use a [regex capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472951/using-regex-matched-groups-in-pandas-dataframe-replace-function), so the `r'\1'` in the replace-expression matches the `(.*)` in the pattern.

Ditto df2.

Then you can simply create df3 with **`df1.merge(df2, ...)`**
See the documentation on `merge(..., how='left'/'right'/'outer'/'inner')` to figure out which type of merge you want; I think you need 'outer'. (If you get stuck on the merge syntax, edit your question to update it)
You will get NaN rows given that df1 has ~130 rows but df2 has ~380. See the .doc on `fillna()` for that.

Comment: Thank you so much smci for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the solution in full details:

```
# add the keyword as index value to df1
df1 = df1.set_index(df1['Symbol_1'].str.replace('(.*)USDT', r'\1', regex=True))

# add the exact keyword as index value to df2
df2 = df2.set_index(df2['Symbol_2'].str.replace('(.*)BTC', r'\1', regex=True))

now both dataframes share the same index value

# set default index name for df1 to 'Key'
df1.index.name = 'Key'

# set default index name for df2 to 'Key'
df2.index.name = 'Key'

# merge df2 to df1 (search both dataframes' column name = 'Key' that share the same value, add the columns from the returned rows to df1)
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='Key')

# drop the default index column and re-index with number
df_reindexed=df3.reset_index(drop=True)

# finally, rename the column names if you want, it's easy to do that.
```

Thanks again to smci for the solution.

> Then you can simply create df3 with df1.merge(df2, ...) See the
> documentation on merge(..., how='left'/'right'/'outer'/'inner') to
> figure out which type of merge you want; I think you need 'outer'. (If
> you get stuck on the merge syntax, edit your question to update it)
> You will get NaN rows given that df1 has ~130 rows but df2 has ~380.
> See the .doc on fillna() for that.

smci, df1 has 130 rows, df2 has 380 rows, I only need 130 rows from df2. so there won't be any NaN rows at all.